# How to prevent page reload when switching between calendar view displays?

Tags: ajax, datetime

I created a Calendar view, and I put **yes** on the setting "use Ajax"

This setting works only for **next** and **previous** buttons.

I would like to have the page doesn't reload while the user switches between different view displays.

Is it possible to enable the same feature for the tabs *Month,* *Week* and *Day*?

Comment: No, not out of box. You need to write some custom javascript for that and put it into a custom module.

Comment: The Drupal [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module does not do this, but there is an alternative called [Full Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar), give it a try.

Comment: Is there any tutorial somewhere? Can I just create a js file and add it in the .info file of Calendar module?

Comment: I tried but I had problem with jQuery version